# PHP include file from root on subdomain

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/includes/db_connection.php';
```

to include a file from the root on a sub domain

but i am getting this error:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/integra/public_html/support/includes/db_connection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you sure that this file exists?

Comment: That looks like it's including a file in the same location as the curretn script, not the web root.

Comment: positive - in the error its showing its looking in the support folder not the root directory

Comment: use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get the document root.

Answer (score 2):

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/includes/db_connection.php';
```

`__DIR__` is not a *root of the subdomain*.

It is where current file is located.

You need:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../includes/db_connection.php';
```

Also, `dirname(__DIR__)` makes no sense at all. It is equal to `__DIR__`.